# Display image in RVIZ

Tags: ros, opencv, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Is there any way to send a captured image to the rviz and display it in a certain position?

similar to a Basic geometric markers for Rviz (visualization_msgs / Marker.msg)...

The idea is to use opencv to identify objects and capture an image of the object and display it in the position where it was captured.

Example:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322457/display-image-in-rviz/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-04**:
Please attach your image to the question directly. I've given you sufficient karma for that.

Note that if you would review your previous questions and their answers and accept one/some, you'd also receive karma.

**Comment by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on 2019-05-04**:
Thank gvdhoorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks fairly similar to what you want to achieve: https://github.com/lucasw/rviz_textured_quads/tree/image_topic (I haven't tried it however).

See also [Q/A 218502](https://answers.ros.org/question/218502/rviz-display-image-in-3d-scene/) for another option that could be used as a starting point.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2019-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2